# Using Scheme to calculate Newton-Raphson's

Tags: scheme, racket, newtons-method

According to Newton-Raphson's:

*X<sub>n+1</sub> = X<sub>n</sub> - f(X<sub>n</sub>) / f'(X<sub>n</sub>)*

```
(newtonRhap x f fx)

(newtonRhap 0.1 sin cos) => 0

(newtonRhap 2.0 
            (lambda (x) (- (* x x) x 6))             ; f
            (lambda (x) (- (* 2 x) 1  )) ) => 3      ; f'
```

How can I implement this function?

The routine will stop iteration when the change in solution is less than pre-set  tolerance.

I use a global variable for it, `(define TOL 1e-6)`:

```
#lang racket
(define TOL 1e-6)
(define (func f x) (f x))
(define (f x) (- (* x x) x 6))
(define (fx x) (- (* 2 x) 1))
(define x 2.0)
(define (newtonRhap x ff ffx)  
    ( (> (- x (/ ff ffx)) TOL)
      (newtonRhap (- x (/ ff ffx)) ff ffx)  
      (list x) ) )

(display (newtonRhap x (f x) (fx x)) )
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far

Comment: @Óscar López I add my code

Comment: If you just want to copy some code, this looks good: https://gist.github.com/steshaw/ac0f6e5c697cf75bd3ab
(I haven't tried it myself.)

Comment: FYI the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55852661/849891) is wrong. (to a moderator: this comment is not offensive. it is factual.)

Answer (score 0):

Good attempt, you need to modify newtonRaph function to use IF though, like this

```
(define (newtonRhap x ff ffx)
  (if (> (- x (/ ff ffx)) TOL)
      (newtonRhap (- x (/ ff ffx)) ff ffx))
      (list x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing an `if` there:

```
(define (newtonRhap x ff ffx)
    ( if (> (- x (/ ff ffx)) TOL)
      (newtonRhap (- x (/ ff ffx)) ff ffx)
      (list x) ) )
```

Without it you would be calling the result of the Boolean test as a function with the following two forms values as arguments (it could work in a lazy functional language with Church-encoded conditionals, but that's besides the point, and Scheme / Racket is not lazy).

Second, and even more crucially, the last two arguments to `newtonRhap` are *functions*, but you're treating them as if they were *numeric values*. Correcting this gives us

```
(define (nl x)     ; for debugging insight;
   (newline)       ; for production redefine it as
   (display x)     ;    (define (nl x) x)
   x)  

(define (newtonRhap x ff ffx)
  (let ((new-x (nl (- x (/ (ff x) (ffx x))))))  ; Follow The Formula
    ( if (> (abs (- x new-x)) TOL)             ; use abs
      (newtonRhap new-x ff ffx)          ; make next step
      (list new-x) ) ) )        ; return the new x, it's closer to the true result
```

Now we can run

```
(display (newtonRhap x f fx))

3.333333333333333
3.019607843137255
3.0000762951094835
3.000000001164153
3.0(3.0)
>
```